# get the table by passing table header in pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, pypdf, pdfplumber

I have a pdf with multiple tables in it. I need to pass table header and get the respected table

For example:

[image]

I will pass the Table name as "daily historical stock prices & volumes", then it must give above table.

Comment: Unless your PDF is a tagged PDF, you would need some application to process the data and create something from it.

Comment: Can you please share some application name?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to recommend products, it is a place for programming assistance in the product you have researched and are implementing. Try asking on super users website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use pyPDF2 and its attribute to get the results